# Custom commands for selecting a check box in cypress

Tags: javascript, java, testing, cypress

**I have written a custom command for selecting the checkbox based upon the contact name what i provide(Refer the image )** for example I provide Test10 Test10, it does not get selected, However the test case gets  passed without selecting, I tried debugging cname variable is empty  attaching the debugger screen shot as well
[image]

[image]

```
    Cypress.Commands.add("SelecttheContact", (contactName) => { 
    cy.get('tr td:nth-child(2)').each(($el, index, $list) => {
    const cname=$el.find(contactName).text()

    if(cname.includes(contactName))
    {

       // cy.get("tr td:nth-child(1)").eq(index).click()
       // cy.get("input[type='checkbox']").eq(index).click()
       debugger
       $e1.find('checkbox').click()
    }
}) })
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong here, but it looks like you are relying on jquery to do the selection work instead of Cypress. I would have used Cypress selection to find the checkbox.

Did you know about the Cypress Selector Playground?

> The Selector Playground is an interactive feature that helps you:
>
> - Determine a unique selector for an element.
> - See what elements match a given selector.
> - See what element matches a string of text.

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-runner.html#Selector-Playground

There is also an API option to change the priorities of the selector

> The Selector Playground exposes APIs that enable you to:
>
> - Change the default selector strategy
> - Override the selectors that are returned per element

https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/selector-playground-api.html#Syntax

Comment: Thanks Mikkel, yes I am aware of the  Cypress Selector Playground, However I don't want use the CSP, as  I cant select dynamically, as you can see i have wrote a custom command, I  may be passing any contact name  and it should be able to select

Comment: Well, you don't have to pass a literal string to cypress, you can pass a variable like you can to jquery. Anyway, it sounds like you know what you want

Comment: Cypress also uses JQuery ;-) So this should be no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

`.find()` accepts a selector, according to the docu: https://api.jquery.com/find/
So passing a text content will not work. 
`text()` returns an empty string because if a selector is not found in JQuery you always get an object. And functions called onto that object will return default values I think.

Why the tests passes can not be determined from what we see :-)

I suggest you to adjust the selector for your checkbox.

Btw I am not sure, if you can call `cy.get()` within `each()` (the line you have commented out in your code).

Currently I am not at my Laptop, so I can not provide an example for clicking a checkbox. But please try to fix the selector and if it does not work, I can try it for myself.

Comment: Makes sense as per the jquery documentation, However I see that from version 1.6  we can add element as well, I assume that we can also pass the text  (Here in my case it will be the text "test10  test110").

Comment: Just quick clarification ,, refer the image https://ibb.co/sHZ6Fnz  .. I see it can take string as well, is my interpretation  correct?

Comment: Sorry I maybe directed you into the wrong direction. of yourse you can pass a "string". for example you can pass `.find("input[type='checkbox']")`. So you can pass the selector as text content. But you can not do similar stuff as you can do with `cy.get().contains("some text anywhere in the page")`. This will not work with JQuery. see this example: https://codepen.io/JosefBiehler/pen/KKwYxeX